# Solve or Reduce don't work with Integer functions

Tags: equation-solving

I had been trying to limit for some c++ programs, the bigest whole number they can handle is

```
lim = 18446744073709551615
```

and the different functions are:

```
tfn[k_] := Total[Table[n!, {n, k}]]
```

or

```
spd2[n_] := Total[Table[2^i, {i, n}]]
```

the only way I found to know the limit k that do not overflow is

```
klimtfn = For[i = 1, 1 < 100, i++, If[tfn[i] > lim, Break[]]]; i - 1
```

or

```
klimspd2 = For[i = 1, 1 < 100, i++, If[spd2[i] > lim, Break[]]]; i - 1
```

for both cases I found correct answers, my concern is I have used `for`and this is like unfair, surely I must learn something better otherwise.
Thanks for advice.

Comment: What does ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger`` return for you?

Comment: i=1; While[tfn[i] < lim, i++]; i-1

Comment: @J.M. is computer-less  it gives me 9223372036854775807

Comment: Okay. So, you know your `spd2` is a finite geometric series, yes? Equate it to ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger`` and solve for the largest possible index.

Comment: As for the [Kurepa function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242413), it might be possible to do a modified binary search.

Comment: @J. M. is computer-less Yes, I did so, First time try Solve[f[n]==limit,n] but this kind of functions (Series we say in my language) that depend en n being n a Natural number seems that Solver or reduce can not solve,  the option J42161217 gave is more elegant than mine, thank you. I wonder only if there is some kind of modifier or conditional that makes solution not using for or while or do while or repeat ...

Comment: So ``Floor[Log2[1 + Developer`$MaxMachineInteger/2]]`` does not evaluate for you?

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is given a f[n], n being Natural, find the value of n that makes f[n] less than lim, f can be sum of squares, or Fibonacci or number of diferent prime factors... any this works perfect with whis While solution J42161217 gave  ... Remains if it can be done without for, while ..

Comment: how about  Floor[InverseFunction[#! &][lim]]

Comment: @J42, yes, that should work for factorials. For sums of factorials as in the OP, something more elaborate is needed.

Comment: Well, this is what we have, the while advice of J42161217 gave a more clean look, I asked about some other option or modifier in Solve or Reduce or FullWhoKnows that I had not found... Thank you all sincerely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica can do the sums symbolically, after which you can use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) *(actually, the symbolic sum isn't necessary, as can be seen by replacing `=` with `:=` in the following)*. First example:

```
f[k_] = Sum[n!, {n, k}]
```

> -1 - Subfactorial[-1] + (-1)^(1 + k) Gamma[2 + k] Subfactorial[-2 - k]

Using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot):

```
k1 = k /. FindRoot[f[k]== 18446744073709551615, {k, 40},WorkingPrecision->16]
```

> 20.65081840115899

Check:

```
Sum[n!, {n, Floor[k1]}] < 18446744073709551615 < Sum[n!, {n, Floor[k1]+1}]
```

> True

For your second example:

```
g[k_] = Sum[2^i, {i, k}]
```

> 2 (-1 + 2^k)

Using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot):

```
k2 = k /. FindRoot[g[k] == 18446744073709551615, {k, 100}]
```

> 63.

Check:

```
Sum[2^i, {i, Floor[k2]}] < 18446744073709551615 < Sum[2^i, {i, Floor[k2]+1}]
```

> True

Comment: FindRoot  !!  this is  Thanks   it works for all my "Series"